# Is there a slang term for a mailbox?

Tags: slang

I'm searching for slang terms for standard mailboxes like the image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a current slang term for this type of mailbox. Nevertheless, the terms *Joroleman's Tunnel* or *Joroleman's Quonset,* taken liberally from information on Wikipedia may, one day, become common slang.